# Как ввести несколько слов на одной строчке. (string)

Tags: c++, строки, visual-studio-2017

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    string ew_1, rw_1;
    getline(cin, ew_1);
    cout << " - ";
    getline(cin, rw_1);
    return 0;
}
```

Здравствуйте! У меня такая проблема. Мне нужно, что бы я мог на одной и той же строчке записать (англ слов) - (тире) (рус слово). Все это должно быть на одной строчке! Но меня после ввода первого слова, переносит на следующую строчку. Как сделать так, что бы все было на одной. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать первый вариант функции [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) с символом разделителем. Но символ '-' придется вводить руками. Например:

```
cout << "Input: ";
getline(cin, ew_1, '-');
getline(cin, rw_1, '\n');

cout << "Output: " << ew_1 << " - " << rw_1;
```

Тогда в консоли:

```
Input: hello-привет
Output: hello - привет
```

Также может быть полезно: [How do I input variables using cin without creating a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209370/how-do-i-input-variables-using-cin-without-creating-a-new-line)